result involving derivative implies polynomial
I've stumbled upon the following exercise and I have no clue as to how one would prove the following statement :

let $f$ be a real valued function, such that:

$f$ has a non positive fourth derivative on $\mathbb{R}$
$f$ is positive on $\mathbb{R}$

Then $f$ is a polynomial of degree strictly less than 3.

Any help would be appreciated.

First of all, notice that polynomial functions of degree strictly less than $3$ are exactly the functions $f$ derivable three times such that $f^{(3)} = 0$. From here, a reformulation of the exercice would be "show that any function $f$ derivable four times such that $f > 0$ and $f^{(4)} \leqslant 0$ verifies $f^{(3)} = 0$". Moreover, a polynomial of degree $3$ can't be positive hence it is enough to verify that $f^{(4)} = 0$.
Consider a function $f$ verifying the wanted hypothesis and assume that $f^{(4)} \neq 0$. $f^{(4)} \leqslant 0$ thus $f^{(3)}$ decreases and it is non constant because $f^{(4)} \neq 0$. In particular, we either have $f^{(3)}(x) \leqslant -\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x$ large enough, or $f^{(3)}(x) \geqslant \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x$ small enough. Up to replacing $f$ by $x \mapsto f(-x)$, we may assume we are in the first situation.
Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \geqslant x_0$, $f^{(3)}(x) \leqslant -\varepsilon$. Then, for all $x \geqslant x_0$, by Taylor integral formula, when $x \rightarrow +\infty$,
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = f(x_0) + (x - x_0)f'(x_0) + \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2}f''(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \frac{(x - t)^2}{2}f^{(3)}(t) \, dt\\
& \leqslant -\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\int_{x_0}^x (x - t)^2 \, dt + \mathrm{O}(x^2)\\
& = -\frac{\varepsilon}{6}(x - x_0)^3 + \mathrm{O}(x^2)\\
& = -\frac{\varepsilon}{6}x^3 + \mathrm{O}(x^2).
\end{align*}
This quatity is negative for $x$ large enough, we even have $f(x) \rightarrow -\infty$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$. It contradicts the hypothesis $f > 0$.

I dont get why $(x-x_0)$ becomes $x$ on that last line, is the equal sign a typo @Cactus?

The difference is absorbed in the $\mathrm{O}(x^2)$.
